# In Pine not possible to loop over different confirguation of a script?

Tags: pine-script

I would like to test my strategy with on different timeframes, trading pairs and parameter values.

For this I would like to build a script with nested loops, a bit like this (pseudo code):

```
for pair in [EURUSD, BTCUSD, ETHBNB]:

    for tf in [5m, 15m, 1h, 4h]

        for va1 in [1, 2, 3, 4]:

            for va2 in [0.2, 0.5]:

                perform_strategy()
                write results somewhere
```

But after having read the doc I am afraid this is not possible with Pine. Could someone confirm ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

However, you can have different variables for different conditions and calculate the results separately. Then you can print the results in a table. It won't be easy tho but depending on your needs, it might work.